SQLAlchemy does not connect to SQL Server with ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server but pyodbc does
I am working on a windows pc and cannot connect to my Microsoft SQL server with SQLAlchemy.
I have the login credentials as follows: IP, Server name, user name, database, password.
I can't use windows authorization since I want to run the finished script off an r, pi or cloud service periodically throughout the day.
password = 'xxx'
server = os.environ['xxx']
database = os.environ['xxx']
username = os.environ['xxx']
driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}' #does not work with pyodbc if + used instead of {}

connection_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver={driver};Encrypt=False"

try:
    # Create the SQLAlchemy engine
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    
    # Test the connection
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        # Use the inspector to get table names
        inspector = inspect(connection)
        tables = inspector.get_table_names()
        
        # Print the list of tables
        print("Tables in the database:")
        for table in tables:
            print(table)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to the database: {e}")

I am able to connect to the server without issue using pyodbc only.
connection_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password};TrustServerCertificate=Yes;'

try:
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    print("Connection successful!")
    connection.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to the database: {e}")

When trying to use SQLAlchemy I either get an 08001, IM0002 or IM0012 Error depending on what I do to the connect string.
In driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}' I have also tried + instead of spaces with and without {}
I have also tried with and without TrustedServerCertificate=Yes/True and Encrypt=False/No
I expected that SQLAlchemy would have connected as easily pyodbc but I can't get it to work.
I also tried the method suggested here.
Full error:

Error connecting to the database: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM012', '[IM012] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Please include the full error, not the code.

Depending on how the connection string is configured I'll either get an 08001 - Client unable to establish connection,  IM0002 - Data source name not found and no default driver specified or IM0012 - DRIVER keyword syntax error. A am currently stuck with an IM0012 Error code.

For a SQLAlchemy connection URL, the querystring separator is &, not ;. Also, Encrypt=False is not valid, use Encrypt=no.
I usually recommend that people use URL.create() to build their connection URL:
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="scott",
    password="tiger^5HHH",
    host="192.168.0.199",
    database="test",
    query={"driver": "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server", "Encrypt": "no"}
)

Then, if you want to see the stringified URL with the password hidden, just print it.
print(connection_url)
"""
mssql+pyodbc://scott:***@192.168.0.199/test?Encrypt=no&driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server
"""


Thank you I will give it a try. I forgot to mention that I don't have the IP of the server. can I still use URL.create()?

I received this error when I tried the suggestion Error connecting to the database: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\r\n (-2146893019) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection.
I think this has to do with using the server name instead of the IP and URL.create() does not have a 'server' argument.

so I used ping to get the IP and ran into the same error message as above.

host= can be a DNS name like host="server01.example.com". Try using "TrustServerCertificate": "yes" instead of "Encrypt": "no"

I was able to get the connection with "TrustServerCertificate": "yes" and "Encrypt": "no"
What will I need to do to get encryption to work? I will be using this script to move proprietary information and need it to be encrypted.

So you tried with "TrustServerCertificate": "yes" and "Encrypt": "yes" and it didn't work?

"TrustServerCertificate": "yes" and "Encrypt": "yes" did not work. Default for encrypt is yes.
